# Is the graph of (x^2/4) + y^4 = 1 an ellipse?

Tags: polynomials

My first thought was that it was not an ellipse because it was not because y was not to the 2nd power. But I decided to graph it to find out. I graphed the following four equations: y = +/-[(+/-) (1-(x^2/4))^1/2]^1/2. I got 2 imaginary values for y and 2 real values for y. The graph of the function was an ellipse with a=2 and b=1. Is this the correct solution? Thank you.

T. Grode

Comment: What is the definition of an ellipse?

Comment: Your first thought was right. The graph does not have all the properties of ellipse.

Comment: Maybe of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superellipse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an ellipse.

If it were a circle (a special case of an ellipse) then you'd be able to find a point in the plane $P$ (the centre) such that the distance from $P$ to every point $X$ on the curve, written $|XP|$, is constant.

If it were a "proper" ellipse then you would be able to find two, and only two, points in the plane $P_1$ and $P_2$ (the foci) such that $|XP_1|+|XP_2|$ is constant for all $X$.

http://www.mathwords.com/e/ellipse.htm

Answer (score 0):

I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph%20(x%5E2)%2F4%20%2B%20y%5E4%20%3D%201) to graph
$$\frac{x^2}{4}+y^4=1$$
and the resulting plot is shown in the image below:

[image: Not an ellipse.]

To cut the long story short, this is certainly **not** an ellipse.